# Django saving media file outside of MEDIA_ROOT when in Docker Container

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a Dockerized website which uses nginx to serve a react.js frontend, a postgreql, and a django backend. It is set to create a summary image (.PNG) which gets saved to an imageField and this is then attached to an email and sent to users. When I run it in in the Django development environment (./manage.py runserver) it works perfectly. However, when I run it using docker-compose, it saves the images into  BASE_DIR and not MEDIA_ROOT. Of note, the static files work.

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/django_static/'  # original one
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_static')  

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
class SummaryEmail(models.Model):
    """Model to represent a new learner/attending combination to only send 1 morning email"""

    learner = models.ForeignKey("learners.Fellow", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    attending = models.ForeignKey("attendings.Supervisor", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    surgery_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    # surgery_type = models.ForeignKey("track.Surgery", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) #Need to make foreign key
    date_surgery = models.DateField()
    email_sent = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="summary email has been sent", null=False, default=False)
    email_body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_email_sent = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    gears_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="email_images/%Y/%m/%d", blank=True)
    steps_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="email_images/%Y/%m/%d", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.learner} & {self.attending} ({self.surgery_type}, {self.date_surgery})"
```

nginx default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }
    location /djangoadmin {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    }

    location /rest-auth {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }
    location /api-auth {
        try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }
#     location /admin {
#         try_files $uri @proxy_api;
#     }

    location @proxy_api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass   http://backend:8000;
    }

    location /django_static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/backend/nabuconnect/django_static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/backend/nabuconnect/media/;
    }
}
```

where I mage the image and save it

```
image_object = dsum.Fellow_summary_tables(cleaned['learner'])

    print('location 1: gears image')
    print('create gears image')
    try:
        image_field = new_email.gears_image # this is the image field of the object in the models.py
        print('have image_field')
        img_name = 'gears_table.png'

        gears_image = image_object.gears_table()

        print('save gears image')
        image_field.save(img_name, InMemoryUploadedFile(
            gears_image,  # file
            None,  # field_name
            img_name,  # file name
            'image/png',  # content_type
            gears_image.tell,  # size
            None)  # content_type_extra
                         )
    except Exception as e:
        print("GEARS EXCEPTION")
        print(e)
```

docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    nginx:
        container_name: nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/backend/nabuconnect/django_static
            - ./docker/nginx/development:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - media_volume:/app/backend/nabuconnect/media
        env_file:
            - ./.env.dev
        depends_on:
            - backend

    backend:
        restart: unless-stopped
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile
        entrypoint: /app/docker/backend/wsgi-entrypoint.sh
        env_file:
            - ./.env.dev
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/backend/nabuconnect/django_static
            - media_volume:/app/backend/nabuconnect/media
        expose:
            - 8000
        depends_on:
            -   db
    db:
        image: postgres:12.3-alpine
        volumes: 
          - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # use to bind-mount
        env_file:
          - ./.env.dev
        ports:
          - '5432:5432'
        expose:
          - 5432

    db_backups:
        image: prodrigestivill/postgres-backup-local
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./db_backups:/backups
        links:
            - db
        depends_on:
            - db
        env_file:
          - ./.env.dev
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_EXTRA_OPTS=-Z6 --schema=public --blobs
            - SCHEDULE=@daily
            - BACKUP_KEEP_DAYS=7
            - BACKUP_KEEP_WEEKS=4
            - BACKUP_KEEP_MONTHS=6
            - HEALTHCHECK_PORT=8080

    redis:
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: redis:7.0.5-alpine
        #    ports:
        #      - '6379:6379'
        expose:
          - 6379

    celery-worker:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile
        restart: unless-stopped
        entrypoint: /app/docker/backend/worker-entrypoint.sh
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/backend/nabuconnect/django_static
        env_file:
          - ./.env.dev
        depends_on:
          - backend
          - redis
        links:
          - redis

    celery-beat:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/backend/Dockerfile
        restart: unless-stopped
        entrypoint: /app/docker/backend/beat-entrypoint.sh
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/backend/nabuconnect/django_static
        env_file:
          - ./.env.dev
        links:
          - celery-worker
          - redis
        depends_on:
          - celery-worker
          - redis
          - backend

volumes:
    static_volume:
    media_volume:
```

wsgi-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

until cd /app/backend/nabuconnect
do
    echo "Waiting for server volume..."
done

echo "collecting static"
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
gunicorn nabuconnect.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4 --threads 4
```

Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile

FROM python:3.8.1

# install nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx vim -y --no-install-recommends
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

# Create a working directory for the django project
#RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
#WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir /app # un commented 2/27/2023
WORKDIR /app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#COPY requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}

ADD ./backend/requirements.txt /app/backend/

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
#RUN pip3 install 'django==3.0.4'
#RUN pip3 install gunicorn
RUN pip3 install -r backend/requirements.txt

#Copy project files into the workign directory
#COPY . .
#Copy font files
COPY ./resources/Helvetica-Font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
ADD ./docker /app/docker
ADD ./backend /app/backend
```

in my module that access the email object and calls for email.gears_image I get

```
nabu_prod-backend-1        | [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/email_images/2023/04/26/gears_table_bQmiNa6.png'
```

The image appears to be created in docker but is also saved in the root folder

In the container...

```
# find . -name steps_table.png
./backend/nabuconnect/email_images/2023/04/26/steps_table.png
```

This is all explained above but I am expecting it to save the image in the MEDIA_ROOT and then attach to an email.

Comment: docker-compose and nginx config look fine. Even if something was wrong with BASE_DIR / WORKDIR normal code flow could not make MEDIA_ROOT disappear from file path - it could show up in wrong place but not disappear. Thus there is a flaw in saving files or debug info is misleading. `find . -name steps_table.png` why searching for this file if `gears_table_bQmiNa6.png` is missing? `steps_table.png` could be the garbage copied during docker image build.

Comment: And it looks like you reuse database created while debugging locally. Are you sure you're trying to open _newly uploaded file_ after migrating to docker-compose setup? If not, if you're reaching file uploaded during "local" run then you only have record in DB, not the file. All media files "disappeared" once you've mapped `/app/backend/nabuconnect/media` to virtual docker volume if i'm not mistaken.